# How to get more detailed code highlighting in visual studio 2015 c#

Tags: c#, wpf, text-editor

I am learning WPF using C# in VS Community 2015. I find it frustrating that methods that are part of the framework do not have a different color in the code highlighting.

For example:

```
_textBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(property, value);
```

`ApplyPropertyValue` is not colored.

Is there a way to turn this on in options or even better a code code highlighting plugin?

I am running sample code from a book and it would be great to know which methods are built in parts of the framework etc.

Comment: Never heard plugin like that. Because a method is a method. And there are no differences between "from microsoft" or "from someone else". You can use your mouse over the method to see the details. If the namespace begins with System...., then it comes from framework.

Comment: Thanks, the mouse over does help somewhat. But I find the overall highlighting less helpful than it could be. Does anybody have any tips on options that can be set for better code highlighting in c#?